# Concatenate a GeojsonFeatureCollection

Tags: javascript, geojson

I have an featureCollection Object and I want to fill it with values through a loop that takes values from another object. Here is what I did:

```
  for (var key in data){
                 var geoJsonFeatureCollection = {
                     type: 'FeatureCollection',
                     features: 
                     {
                         type: 'Feature',
                         geometry: {
                             type: 'Point',
                             coordinates: [data[key].YO, data[key].XO]
                         },
                         properties: {
                             "origin_city": data[key].Origin,
                             "origin_lat": data[key].YO,
                             "origin_lon": data[key].XO,
                             "destination_city": data[key].Destination,
                             "destination_lat": data[key].Y,
                             "destination_lon": data[key].X

                         }
                     }};
                 }
```

But I need to place the loop inside the geoJsonFeatureCollection, how to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

This might work.

```
for (var key in data){

    for (var i = 0; i < otherObj.length; i++) {   //Other object
            if (otherObj[i].city  ===data[key].Origin) {  //fields join on.

                 var geoJsonFeatureCollection = {
                     type: 'FeatureCollection',
                     features: 
                     {
                         type: 'Feature',
                         geometry: {
                             type: 'Point',
                             coordinates: [data[key].YO, data[key].XO]
                         },
                         properties: {
                             "origin_city": data[key].Origin,
                             "origin_lat": data[key].YO,
                             "origin_lon": data[key].XO,
                             "destination_city": data[key].Destination,
                             "destination_lat": data[key].Y,
                             "destination_lon": data[key].X,

                            "DataFieldtoAdd": otherObj[i].DataField  // from Joined 

                     }
```